# Excel: Highlighting datetime cell that is greater than now. Dynamic values

Tags: excel

I know that you need to keep the date in the cell in order to evaluate time with conditional formatting. I want to concatenate the dynamic date, today(), with a static hour (I will have several values: 9:00 AM, 10:00 AM, 1:00 PM.)

Say, A1 is today()
B1 is 9:00 AM
C1 has the formula: concat(a1,' ',b1)

I then get this mess: 45120 0.375

How do I format the values so it appears as 7/13/2023 5:58PM?

The idea is to create a call list where I can dynamically highlight times that are not within call times.

I tried formatting the values by right clicking. That doesn't seem to work. I'm starting to think it cannot be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datetimes are numbers. Numbers should not be concatenated, they should be added.

Instead of

```
=CONCAT(A1," ",B1)
```

try

```
=A1+B1
```

The result should be a number that you can format as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

for current date and time, use now() function, which will give you current date, time.
and now format the cell in which you want data to be highlighted,
format this cell with "Format only cell with value greated than" now() and colour it with your colour.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYxop.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).